# How to call a Java function which connects to Database?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jsp

I have a Java class which connects to an Oracle database and a JSP page, in which I am trying to call the function which connects to the database

I am getting a NullPointerException when the function is called.

My Java code:

```
public class DBConnection 
{
public Connection getConnection() throws Exception
  {   

 Connection con = null;
    try {
      Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

      con = DriverManager.getConnection(the correct code);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;

    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
 }

}
```

and my JSP page:

```
<% DBConnection db=new DBConnection(); 

db.getConnection(); 
 %>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: did you add the necessary jars?

Comment: @FlorescentTicker yes all the jars are added

Comment: you should not access database through jsp. Instead use servlets for that purpose. Post the stacktrace.

Comment: Your function does not return anything! Put your real code please.

Comment: Either give the real code or complete error trace

Answer (score 0):

Use `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");` instead. oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver is deprecated starting from Oracle 9i.